# AWS Lambda - Asynchronously invoked function but nothing happens

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I have 2 lambda functions, my first function w/c we'll call "PostStep" invokes another lambda function "RetryStep" asynchronously whenever a timeout occurs. It's been working fine ever since. Now I have to do some code changes, and during testing, a weird issue occurred.

Upon timeout, it still calls the RetryStep function asynchronously, but then the function is not really being invoked. I tried invoking the PostStep function again, then I noticed that's the time when the RetryStep function is really invoked, but with the previous request's data.

Here's how I'm doing the invocation:

**LivePostingService.class**

```
  @Override
  public void postTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    ... some posting logic ...
    conditionalCallRetryLambdaFunction(transaction);
  }

  private void conditionalCallRetryLambdaFunction(Transaction transaction) {
    try {
        String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(transaction);
        lambdaInvokerService.invokeAsync(lambdaRetryFunctionName, payload);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        if(LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
  }
```

**LambdaInvokerService.class**

```
   @Service
   public class LambdaInvokerServiceImpl implements LambdaInvokerService {

    LOGGER.info("Calling lambda function: " + functionName + ", with payload: " + payload);
    InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
            .withFunctionName(functionName)
            .withInvocationType(InvocationType.Event)
            .withPayload(payload);

    AsyncHandler<InvokeRequest, InvokeResult> asyncHandler = new AsyncHandler<InvokeRequest, InvokeResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InvokeRequest request, InvokeResult invokeResult) {
            LOGGER.info("Success! " + invokeResult);
        }
    };

    lambdaAsyncClient.invokeAsync(req, asyncHandler);
   }
```

Here's my handler:

```
@Override
public Void handleRequest(DynamodbEvent dynamodbEvent, Context context) {
     livePostingService.postTransaction(transaction);
     return null;
}
```

As you can see from the code, the log *Calling lambda function..* appears at the end of PostStep function, but the log *Success!* appears at the beginning of the PostStep function if i invoke it again.

It's the same code with what's currently on our production. I even did a git checkout on our master branch then ran it on dev, but the same issue still occurs. Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: "As you can see from the code, the log Calling lambda function.. appears at the end of PostStep .." No, we cannot see it. Please extend your code.

Comment: @AakashVerma I edited my post. thanks!